# Error when deleting user mvc 4 using SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

When I try `Membership.DeleteUser(string, bool)` in a MVC 4 project where I use `SimpleMembership` provider, I get following error message:

> "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "fk_UserId".  The conflict occurred in database "Conductor_Basic3",
>   table "dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles", column 'UserId'. The statement has
>   been terminated."

The constraints is set and is correct, so I can't really understand the error message. I guess I've missed something here.

Can anyone explain to me this error?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the table webpages_Roles has reference to your user, you should to exclude user from role, and after that you able to delete user, try this:

```
 Roles.RemoveUserFromRole("UserName","RoleName");
 Membership.DeleteUser("UserName");
```

Or you can try to use another approach: explicitly specify cascade deletion in your db like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the foreign key constraint doesn't let you delete rows from the user table because they have matching rows in dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles tables. I am not very familiar with default Membership Provider schema but you have to make sure you delete the rows in dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles for getting past that error.

Comment: The stupid thing is that those membership tables are installed by a little command-line script and SHOULD be cascading out of the box. But you are right, it's just a little annoying that the script gets you 95% where you want to go and then doesn't tell you that you need to take a few more steps. But this is nothing compared to what Oracle does to you.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
{
    var tmpuser = "";
    var ctx = new UsersContext();
    using (ctx)
    {
        var firstOrDefault   = ctx.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(us => us.UserId==id);
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
            tmpuser = firstOrDefault.UserName;
    }

    string[] allRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(tmpuser);
    Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(tmpuser,allRoles);

    //Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(tmpuser, "RoleName");

    ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount(tmpuser);
    Membership.Provider.DeleteUser(tmpuser, true);
    Membership.DeleteUser(tmpuser, true);

    ctx = new UsersContext();

    return View(ctx.UserProfiles.OrderBy(user => user.UserName).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and solved it by expanding @testCoder 's answer a bit.

```
var rolesProvider = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
var roles = rolesProvider.GetRolesForUser(username);
if (roles != null && roles.Length > 0)
{
    rolesProvider.RemoveUsersFromRoles(new[] { username }, roles);
}
Membership.DeleteUser(username, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was given by [testCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346297/testcoder), here is some implementation which worked fine for me...

```
Public Shared Sub DeleteUser(User As String)
    Dim UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User)
    If UserRoles.Count > 0 Then Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(User, UserRoles)
    DirectCast(Membership.Provider, WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider).DeleteAccount(User)
    DirectCast(Membership.Provider, WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider).DeleteUser(User, True)
End Sub
```